# How to remove minimum number of points of two sets such that their respective convex hulls are disjoint??

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-geometry

Suppose we are given two set of points A and B in a 2D plane, and their convex hulls are not disjoint, how to remove minimum number of points so that they become disjoint?

Answer (score -1):

Let $c(A)$ denote the convex hull of the set of points $A$, then remove the points $(c(A)\cap c(B))\cap A$ or $(c(A)\cap c(B))\cap B$, whichever has lesser points.

Comment: This removes points it doesn't need to remove. Say that $A$ and $B$ are (the vertices of) two triangles, $A$ contains a point in $c(B)$, and $B$ has a point in $c(A)$. Your proposal is to get rid of both of those points, but the convex hulls become disjoint as soon as we get rid of one.

Comment: @Abishanka saha This does not work when one convex hull lies completely inside the other, in that case this removes all the points of A or B

Comment: I have edited. It works now.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha Thank You so much. I still have a doubt, what if one of the convex hulls lies completely inside the other.. in this case according to your formula we have to remove all the points from A or B, but still a solution is possible by removing some of the boundary of A or B

Comment: No. If $A\subset B$ then $c(A)\subseteq c(B)$.

Comment: Also note you are only removing points of $A$ or points of $B$, not both.

Comment: So, isn't there any solution possible if we remove points from both the sets?

Comment: This does not work at all -- imagine for example, $A$ consists of two opposite corners of a convex quadrilateral and $B$ are the two other corners. Then  Then $c(A)\cap c(B)$ is nonempty (it consists of the single point where the two diagonals intersectg) but neither $c(A)\cap c(B)\cap A$ nor $c(A)\cap c(B)\cap B$ will suggest any points to remove.